# How to use the indexed color mode in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting

i want to understand the indexed color mode please hep me out how to work with indexed color mode.

Comment: Try googling it: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color), [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/color-modes.html). What in particular do you need help with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating 8-bit versions of images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61934/generating-8-bit-versions-of-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexed color mode is basically for GIFs, which were designed to use a limited palette of 256 (or fewer) colors. Those could be from a standard palette, or coordinated with an image.
It's a fascinating topic. See this for more info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color